# Converting JSON into Seq<String> in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala and trying to achieve the following using Scala's foldLeft() method or any other functional solution:

I have the following JSON:

```
 {
   "aspects": [
     {
       "name": "Name",
       "values": [
         "Phone"
       ]
     },
     {
       "name": "Color",
       "values": [
         "Red",
         "Black"
       ]
     },
     {
       "name": "Size",
       "values": [
         "6",
         "10"
       ]
     }
   ]
 }
```

I want to convert this into the following `Seq<String>`:

`["Name:::Phone", "Color:::Red", "Color:::Black", "Size:::6", "Size:::10"]`

I did that using Java style where `aspects` is an object representing the JSON:

```
 aspects.foreach(pair => {
   pair.values.foreach(value => {
     valuesList += pair.name + ":::" + value
   })
 })
```

What is the best Scala's way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the JSON library you are using, but once you have the `aspects` data in a suitable format the output can be generated is like this:

```
case class Aspect(name: String, values: Seq[String])

val aspects: Seq[Aspect] = ???

aspects.flatMap(a => a.values.map(a.name + ":::" + _))
```

I use `json4s` and `jackson` and the conversion code is basically just

```
val aspects = parse(json).extract[Seq[Aspect]]
```

Check the documentation for details, and check out other JSON libraries which may be more suitable for your application.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Comment: BEWARE: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk is constantly promoting his own JSON library.

Comment: Tim, if you are using json4s really then I feel sorry for your clients, who are misled by your decisions. Can it be explanation why you are hidden by some nick here?

Comment: JSON is used in many places where there are no "clients" and any issues that you allege are irrelevant. Please, please stop spamming threads about JSON with promotions for your personal library.

Comment: It looks that you are not just using, but also promoting unsafe and inefficient library like json4s here. There is a bunch of handier, safer and performant option instead ;)

Comment: I am not promoting anything, you are promoting your own code for personal gain.

Answer (score 0):

Have not parsed the JSON since the object aspects has these values. Just manually constructing the case class and flatmapping it

```
scala> final case class Aspects(pairs:Seq[Pair])
defined class Aspects

 val namepair = Pair("Name",Seq("Phone"))
namepair: Pair = Pair(Name,List(Phone))

 val colorpair = Pair("Color",Seq("Red","Black"))
colorpair: Pair = Pair(Color,List(Red, Black))

 val sizepair = Pair("Size",Seq("6","10"))
sizepair: Pair = Pair(Size,List(6, 10))

 val aspects = Aspects(Seq(namepair,colorpair,sizepair))
aspects: Aspects = Aspects(List(Pair(Name,List(Phone)), Pair(Color,List(Red, Black)), Pair(Size,List(6, 10))))

aspects.pairs.flatMap(pair=>pair.values.map(value=>s"${pair.name}:::$value"))
res1: Seq[String] = List(Name:::Phone, Color:::Red, Color:::Black, Size:::6, Size:::10)
```

Comment: P.S. Saw after posting , Tim has an earlier answer